# Does anyone have a C# example of using an UltraDataSource as the DataSource to a UltraComboEditor please

Tags: combobox, datasource, infragistics

Does anyone have a C# example of using an UltraDataSource as the DataSource to a UltraComboEditor please.

I can get so far but it doesn't seem to bind.

Comment: Are you talking of the UltraCombo or the UltraComboEditor?. They are really different controls with different functionality

Comment: I'm talking about the UltraComboEditor (not UltraCombo). I'm using a standalone control (not embedded in a grid).

Comment: Do you have set the property DataMember to `Band 0` or something different from blank text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a simple project to use an `UltraDataSource` as datasource for a simple `UltraComboEditor`.  Set the properties of the ComboEditor to

```
        this.ultraComboEditor1.DataMember = "Band 0";
        this.ultraComboEditor1.DataSource = this.udsTest;   // <- crashed here
        this.ultraComboEditor1.DisplayMember = "Description";
        this.ultraComboEditor1.Name = "ultraComboEditor1";
        this.ultraComboEditor1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

The sample program crashed with a NullReferenceException inside the `InitializeComponent` code where I set the UltraDataSource instance.

Then I have removed the setting of the property `DataMember`  (Not just blanked out, but right-click and selected Reset). Now the program works.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks Steve. That's put me on the right track. Within my DataSource InitSchema I was setting the Band.Key but not using that value in the ultraComboEditor1.DataMember. Thanks.